# Difference between the * and & operator in function calls

Tags: c++, function, dereference, address-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ functions: ampersand vs asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670101/c-functions-ampersand-vs-asterisk)
>   [What are the distinctions between the various symbols (*,&, etc) combined with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636903/what-are-the-distinctions-between-the-various-symbols-etc-combined-with-p)

I am wondering the difference between the address operator `&` and the deference operator `*` in a C++ function call. For example take the following function

```
void foo (std::string& param)
{
     param = "Bar.";
     std::cout << param.size();
}
```

and let's call it in our `main()` function like so...

```
int main()
{
      std::string test;
      foo(test);          //Why not foo(&test)?
      std::cout << test;  //Prints out the value "Bar."
}
```

First off, why does the `&` operator allow me to assign a value as if it were a pointer (assigning it a value that survives the RAII and scope of the function `foo()` when it's not a pointer) as it is able to be printed out in my `main()` function even though it's not `static`? I am assuming it is not a pointer because I am able to access the `size()` method by using the `.` operator instead of the `->` which is used for pointers.

Secondly, what would be the difference between using the `&` operator in a function parameter vs. using the `*` operator? Is it even different than just a plain variable like `std::string param`? It appears to be called like that (`foo(test)` instead of `foo(&test)`).

Comment: Have a closer look at C++ *references*.

Comment: It's not an operator, it's a reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/), [C++ functions: ampersand vs asterisk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/670101/), [difference between ampersand “&” and asterisk “*” in function/method declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/596636/), [What are the differences between parameter definitions as (type& name), and (type* name)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/948947/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` function parameter specifically signifies that this parameter is being passed-in by **reference** (traditionally compilers implement this as a pointer) which is why you see the effect of this assignment in your `main()`.
`static` would have nothing to do with that.

The difference in declaring a parameter to a function using `&` and `*` is that the second one allows a `nullptr` (or a non-existent or just a plain invalid address) to be passed-in while the `&` guarantees that there's a real object being referenced by this function's argument. Other than that both provide similar functionality of allowing an original object to be changed via it's reference.

Answer (score 0):

`test` on it's own (without `&`) would pass a copy to the string to the function, whilst the `&` means it will pass a reference.

FYI: When you don't need a reference, best-practise dictates passing all objects as const references.